# Google Earth Plugin: toggle layers in a single .kmz?

Tags: google-earth-plugin, kmz

With the Google Earth plugin, is there a way to use checkboxes to toggle individual layers on and off that are all contained in a single .kmz file?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573627/kml-dom-walking-is-slow-how-to-avoid-walking-children)

Basically you assign an 'id' to a folder,placemark,linestring etc
then tell the plug-in to toggle the visibility of the 'id'

Comment: Great thanks a lot! It will take me a few days to test this, but when I do I'll come back and mark your answer as the solution!